# systemd.network DUID, IAID and DHCPv4 clientIdentifier

Tags: dhcp, nixos, systemd-networkd

I've set my NixOS to use: `systemd-networkd`:

```
  systemd.network.enable = true;
```

and I have my interfaces configured something like that:

```
networking {
  interfaces.enp5s0f0np0.useDHCP = true;
  interfaces.enp5s0f1np1.macAddress = cfg.myMacAddress;
  interfaces.enp5s0f1np1.ipv6.addresses = [ {
    address = "fd00:cafe::1";
    prefixLength = 64;
  }];
};
```

Now for `DHCPv4`, I want to fix the `clientIdentifier` (ultimately my DHCP server needs both the `MAC` address and the `clientID` to give a fixed IP); for which I could do something like this:

```
systemd.network.networks."40-enp5s0f1np1" = {
  dhcpV4Config.ClientIdentifier = "duid";
  dhcpV4Config.DUIDType = "vendor";
  dhcpV4Config.IAID = <something>;
};
```

essentially the current defaults for `clientIdentifier` (`duid`) and `DUIDType` (`vendor`). And I could set a `IAID`, once I understand the format it should take.

However, I'd like to figure out how the default `IAID` is generated (so that I can understand how the default `DUID` I get in the `DHCPv4` request is formed).

The idea would be to make sure that my NixOS configuration contains the right amount of details. Right now, I could use the default `DUID`, but I have no idea if it will persist over reboots…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `ClientIdentifier=duid` is selected for DHCPv4, the resulting DHCPv4 client identifier is 0xFF ([type=DUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4361#section-6.1)) + four-byte IAID + the DHCPv6 DUID (which depends on `DUIDType=`).

The default systemd-networkd "vendor" DHCPv6 DUID is based on a **hash of `/etc/machine-id`**. See [`man networkd.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/networkd.conf.html#DUIDType=) for other DUID types available.

The format of an IAID is just a 32-bit integer, used to distinguish multiple IAs with the same DUID. If a custom IAID is not provided, systemd-networkd will generate a stable IAID by hashing the "predictable" name of the interface if one is known (even if that's not the currently active name), or hashing the MAC address otherwise.

`networkctl status eth0` will tell you the DHCPv4 Client ID as well as the DHCPv6 DUID.

The byte format of the `duid` client identifier is as defined in [RFC 4361](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4361#section-6.1):

```
ClientIdentifier=duid
DUIDType=vendor
DHCPv4 Client ID = ff:5d:e2:6c:15:0:2:0:0:ab:11:f9:f9:80:f7:f7:20:2c:f5
                  |--|-----------|-------------------------------------|
  Client ID type = ff                                     (255 = DHCPv6 IAID+DUID)
     DHCPv6 IAID =    5d:e2:6c:15                           (siphash of "enp2s0"?)
     DHCPv6 DUID =                0:2:0:0:ab:11:f9:f9:80:f7:f7:20:2c:f5
                                 |---|---------|-----------------------|
DHCPv6 DUID type =                0:2                                (2 = DUID-EN)
  DUID-EN vendor =                    0:0:ab:11                  (43793 = systemd)
    DUID-EN data =                              f9:f9:80:f7:f7:20:2c:f5
```

As your MAC address is static, it would be much simpler to use `ClientIdentifier=mac`, which always consists of just the MAC address prefixed by 0x01 (type=Ethernet). This is the traditional ID type sent by most other DHCPv4 clients, such as dhclient or Windows, and would look like:

```
ClientIdentifier=mac
DHCPv4 Client ID = 1:4e:c8:ac:b7:d8:4e
                  |-|-----------------|
  Client ID type = 1                     (1 = Ethernet)
Hardware address =   4e:c8:ac:b7:d8:4e
```

Similarly you may use `DUIDType=link-layer` for DHCPv6:

```
DUIDType=link-layer
DHCPv6 DUID = 0:3:0:1:4e:c8:ac:b7:d8:4e
             |---|---|-----------------|
  DUID type = 0:3                         (3 = DUID-LL)
  Link type =     0:1                     (1 = Ethernet)
 LL address =         4e:c8:ac:b7:d8:4e
```

(You could in theory combine `ClientIdentifier=duid` with `DUIDType=link-layer`, but that's a bit redundant, and most DHCP servers have better support for `ClientIdentifier=mac`.)